# need to average several arrays using while loop and shift register

Tags: labview

I have written a vi in labview that converts acquired data to 2D array. Now, I want to use shift register, and what comes out from the loop, would be a 2D array that is average of all 2D arrays after that the loop is stopped by user.
I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

[image: Code]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/293772211.png))</sub>